# Google Service Account Throwing exception (HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Precondition check failed.)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, service-accounts

I am using google service account to read mail from gmail. But it keep giving me following exception.

The service gmail has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Precondition check failed.

I used following method for authentication.

```
public static GmailService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");

            // For Json file
            if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
            {
                GoogleCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
                }


                

                // Create the  Analytics service.
                return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
            {   // If its a P12 file

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the  Gmail service.
                return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountGmailFailed", ex);
        }
    }
```

I gave permission to domain from gsuite. But don't know what went wrong. Can someone help me with it?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Bad request may come from impersonating no user or incorrect user because I see you already did [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority). I would confirm that you have done impersonation for a Admin user using this [example](https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-service-account-in-c-mvc-w/241) in C#

```
 //"SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE";
        String serviceAccountEmail = "test-417@elated-graph-261115.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

        // Scope and user email id which you want to impersonate
        var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = scopes,
            User = "yourEmail@domain.com"
        };
```

Other than that, make sure that you have Google Workspace active account. Yet, this will not work for a personal gmail account - as long as you are going to use service account.